# Flash CS5 Actionscript 3.0 Using a movie clip as a button with linking

Tags: flash, button, actionscript, flash-cs5

So I have an animated button in the form of a movie clip that I want to be able to use as a link. The movie clip is animated on mouse over and mouse off using a script I found online, and that works perfectly. However, when I try to create a simple actionscript command to also have the movie clip act as a link, I get the following error thrown at me:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at PheV3_fla::MainTimeline/frame185()

All of the tutorials I found online use the "button" type for linking as opposed to a movie clip, which seems to work fine, but I need this to be a movie clip for the animation. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent
import flash.net.URLRequest

MixesButtonTop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"), "_blank");
}
```

Do I need to reference one of the symbols inside the movie clip button itself or something? I'm very new to all this so if I missed anything please let me know, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: The compiler is telling you that there is no reference to something. I assume this means your button is not present. Where is the button(=movieclip?) and where is the script? EDIT: Looks like your have a movieclip in your library with class name MixesButtonTop. You need to create an instance of it, either by placing it on the timeline or by script using var b:MovieClip = new MixesButtonTop();

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I did add the line "MixesButtonTop.buttonMode = true;" and the movie clip does exist in the timeline, but let me try adding the "var b:MovieClip = new MixesButtonTop();" and I'll get back to you

Comment: So I tried adding the line mentioned above and I get a new error "Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 184, Line 4 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method MixesButtonTop."

Answer (score 0):

You should give your button an instance name under the properties tab, and then reference to it by that name, and not by how it is called in the library. To do that you need

1. Select the button instance on the Stage.
2. Select Window > Properties, and enter a name in the Instance Name box.

So for example you set instance name `MixesButtonTop`. Then you should declare a variable in your code like this:

```
var buttonMC:MovieClip = MixesButtonTop;
```

And that should fix your problem.

Comment: It did have an instance name but I figured out what the problem was and I'll post the solution here in case anyone else has this problem, apparently both the starting object of the tween I was using and the final object both need to have the same instance name.

Answer (score 0):

If your button exists in the timeline, you need to give it an instance name (see the response of jfgi). By this instance name you can reference it in your code. It is not necessary to assign it to a variable (in contrast to what jfgi wrote) - however assigning it to a variable and adding the type (:MovieClip) will help you with code-hinting if you are working with Flash IDE, otherwise the IDE cannot figure out what type the symbol is. Note: the name of the symbol in the library is a 'Class name' (Linkage). You cannot use the class name to command and INSTANCE of the class. You need to assign it to a variable/give it an instance name in the properties window. If you manually place a symbol from the library to the stage and you want to control it, you 'always' need to add an instance name. ('always'... as there are other ways to retrieve the reference, e.g. getChildAt, etc...)

I had to post this as an answer, it was too long for a comment.